# foreach loop in aspx page - CS1026: ) expected

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

In the following block of code, i got the compilator error : CS1026: ) expected
at that line :

```
"position": <%=node.Attribute("level").Value;%>,
```

Full code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
"itemListElement":

<% foreach (var node in firstLevelChildren) {%>
[{"@type": "ListItem",
"position": <%=node.Attribute("level").Value;%>,
"item":
{"@id": <%=node.Attribute("url").Value; %>,
"name": <%=node.Attribute("nav_title").Value; %>}},
 ]
 <%}%>

 }
</script>
```

I can't understand what's wrong, all the brackets seem to be correctly closed..
Thank you for your help

Comment: at the end of the last line ""name": <%=node.Attribute("nav_title").Value; %>}},"  I see a comma. Maybe you have to check if there are multiple elements in your loop cicle and manage the comma..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the semicolon `;` from all inline values:

```
<% foreach (var node in firstLevelChildren) {%> [{
  "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": <%= node.Attribute("level").Value %>,
  "item": {
    "@id": <%= node.Attribute("url").Value %>,
    "name": <%= node.Attribute("nav_title").Value %>
  }
}, ]
<%}%>
```

also, you're `json` syntax seems to be incorrect, the line before last, troubles me. you should not get a compilation error though, just invalid `json`

instead of

```
   }
}, ]
```

i think it should be

```
   }
} ],
```

the comma should be after each array element